# prepopulate promo code as well as drop off address - deep linking - uber

Tags: uber-api

I am using deep linking to pass the drop off address so when the uber app fires, the address is pre-populated. I have a promo code which i would like to be pre-populated as well.

I understand to prepopulate promo code you could use this:

uber://?action=applypromo&promo=mypromo

The above action doesn't take my other parameter(like drop off address). How can I achieve this in one call?(pre-populate promo code as well as drop off address)?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not supported at the moment.